# How can I use a parameter as key in a new object?

Tags: syntax, key, expression, jq

I'm modifying some swagger to add aws api gateway integrations and am currently stuck on this problem.

Using this code, I'm unable to generate the security object.

I'm getting the error:

`jq: error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting '}' (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 6:
      .value.security |= [ { $authorizer_name : map(.) }]`

This is driving me bonkers today.

Can anyone shed a light on this?

here's a small repro.

```
INPUT='{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "paths": {
    "integrations/systems/{system_id}/configurations": {
      "get": {
        "security": [
          "https://api.com/internal-api"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}'

AUTHORIZER_NAME="cognito_user_pool"

jq --arg authorizer_name "${AUTHORIZER_NAME}" \
'.info.title |= "API" 
| .info.description |= "REST API" 
| .paths |= with_entries(
    .value |= with_entries(
      .value.security |= [ { $authorizer_name : "stuff" }]
    )
  )' <<< "${INPUT}"
```

EDIT:

The solution is to surround the argument with `()` ie. `.value.security |= [ { ($authorizer_name) : "stuff" }]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @JeffMercado suggested, the problem goes away if you enclose `$authorizer_name` in parentheses:

```
{ ($authorizer_name) : "stuff" }
```

The point is that when using the object construction syntax as here, each expression specifying a key name must be enclosed in parentheses unless it is a JSON string.